# 2017 Ford Fiesta manually turning ignition switch

Tags: ford, ignition, fiesta, ignition-switch, smartkey

My 2017 Fiesta's ignition lock cylinder has gone bad. I am currently trying to avoid this problem by disengaging the ignition switch from the lock cylinder and manually turning the ignition with a screwdriver but the car refuses to start.

The car has an anti-theft system using an RFID chip in the key, but I believe this system is bypassed by putting the key in the now-useless lock cylinder as per usual. If I do not have the key there, manually turning the switch will cause a "key missing" message to be displayed by the console. Once the key is in the proper position, turning the ignition switch does nothing except heat itself up. My best guess is the ignition switch needs to interface with another electronic device and being separated from the lock cylinder prevents this, causing the electricity that would start the car to become waste heat. But that guess doesn't make too much sense as the ignition switch doesn't appear to interface with anything besides the lock cylinder and can/should use the still-connected wires to start.

Does anyone know why the ignition wouldn't start the car if the anti theft system has been defeated?

Pictures with descriptions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWLUi.jpg

I figure if I can get this method to work its much cheaper than repairing the lock cylinder and would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: The car will have a steering lock that requires the key to be turned.  Have you disabled the steering lock?

Comment: Are you saying that the electrical switch gets hot when you turn it manually?

Comment: Does the steering lock need the car turned past the 3rd position? I have not disabled the steering lock.

Comment: And yea it gets hot when I rotate the center by inserting a flathead into the notch the lock cylinder normally goes in.

Comment: The steering lock will be disabled by turning the key to the first on position.  Are you saying that you just can’t turn the key to the 3rd ‘start’ position?  Have you tried turning the key to the start position with the electrical switch removed?  This sounds to me like the barrel is ok and that it is the electrical switch that is faulty, because it should never get hot.

Comment: The key can turn to any position but only because I removed parts inside the steering column that weren't turning then put the lock cylinder and plastic circular housing back on. The Ford fiesta lock cylinder doesn't directly interface with the switch, it interfaces with a mess of metal gears and other parts which in turn interfaces with the ignition switch.

Comment: The ignition switch at least partially works since rotating it has the same behavior turning the key normally would, except for starting. Turning the switch a little bit allows me to rotate the steering wheel, shift gear and causes the car to beep if a door is open.